# Aqueduct ignores conroller

Tags: dart, aqueduct

I have two controllers, one resource, the other normal. They are in the same thread and both must run.

I deliberately inserted a sudden return in a normal controller to make sure it was simply ignored.

Regular controller:

```
import 'package:aqueduct/aqueduct.dart';
import 'package:app_server/app_server.dart';

class InputController extends Controller {
  @override
  Future<RequestOrResponse> handle(Request request) async {
    return Response.badRequest();
  }
}
```

Channel:

```
@override
  Controller get entryPoint {
    final router = Router();
    
    router.route("/auth/[:type]")
      ..link(() => InputController())
      ..link(() => AuthorizationController(context));
    
    return router;

  }
```

The channel skips the InputController, and immediately proceeds to the resource controller (AuthorizationController).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it does not skip the `InputController` (you can *printf* inside if you want to belive :) ), but it works on the object returned by `router.route("/auth/[:type]")` instead of on the result of  `InputController`.

In other words, your channel can be written as below:

```dart
@override
  Controller get entryPoint {
    final router = Router();
    
    var router2 = router.route("/auth/[:type]");
      router2 = router2.link(() => InputController())
      router2 = router2.link(() => AuthorizationController(context));
    
    return router;

  }
```

Change [cascade notation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-) to a normal chain in the channel in order to resolve tour problem:

```dart
@override
  Controller get entryPoint {
    final router = Router();
    
    router.route("/auth/[:type]")
      .link(() => InputController())
      .link(() => AuthorizationController(context));
    
    return router;

  }
```

Comment: Oh God. The whole problem was in unnecessary points... Thank you, I still need to study in this topic.